How to catch a sub taskflow suspended status in IICS
Does anybody know how can I catch the status of a sub taskflow in a decision to fail it if it is suspended ?
I have a taskflow that have multiple sub taskflows, each sub taskflow have several mapping tasks with error handling initialized but in case of warning it will just suspend the parent taskflow. From the complete taskflow I want to fail the subtaskflows that get suspened.
I enabled Fault Handling:

And in the decision immediately after it I can read that field called "VIM_RAW_fail" by formula and have 3 parameters:

However, I do not know how to interpret those parameters and which one I could use to catch the "Suspended" status. I do not even know if this is the proper way but I am open to any proposals.
Thank you!

The problem is that Suspended is not Completed. It's not done yet. So AFAIK, it will not be possible to catch that.
